# Not able to submit 2 forms using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Here are my 2 forms which i am trying to submit through ajax & jquery. The 1st form is easily getting submitted. While the 2nd form is not submitted.

1st form -

```
<form method="post" id="formFilter" action="admin-advertiser-search.php">
....
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#formFilter');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
    .....
      }
    }
```

This post function is working fine.

2nd Form -

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#uploadForm');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
    ............
         }
    }
```

This ajax form submission not working.

Kindly suggest any required changes.

Comment: first: your variables have the same name, try changing them to unique names. second: your form variable is already a jqurey element, you only need to write: `form.on('submit' function() { } ` and not `$(form).on('submit', function() { }`.

Comment: first: your variables have the same name, try changing them to unique names.....not understood, which variable

Comment: `var form = ....`. You declare this two times.

Comment: changed the variable name but still it doesn't work

Comment: sorry then all i can say is: create a minimal working example where we can see your problem.